# PHP: How to anchor a variable within a page

Tags: php, config, require

I'm trying to make a simple calculation form using PHP. A page will contain textfileds where users would input numerical values and by hitting a button, an mathematical operation will be performed and output in another textfield.

Here's my code:

```
    <html>

<form name="form01" method="post">
<p>Quantite de vecteur: <input type="text" name="B" /></p>
<p>Taille du vecteur: <input type="text" name="A" /></p>
<p>Taille de l'insert: <input type="text" name="C" /></p>
   <input type="submit" name="ratio_calc" id="ratio_calc" value="calculer">
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['ratio_calc'])) { 

    $A = 'A';
    $B = 'B';
    $C = 'C';
    $ratio = (($B * $C) / $A);

}
?>

p>Le ratio: <input type="text" name="ratio" value=<?php echo $ratio ?> /></p>

</html>
```

So, I would like to $ratio to be outpout in a textfield named "ratio". Pretty easy, and somehow it does work, but I keep getting *Undefined variable: ratio* **before** actually hitting button "calculer".

I'm heavy noob in PHP scripting but I assume that variables A, B, C and ratio are defined within the first part of PHP script, and when the script ends, they are erased. I guess I could fix the problem by fixing or anchoring somehow those variables so that they are kept "in memory" through the file. Is it possible?

I found somewhere that I could use `$config = array(` save it as a PHP file and then call it everytime a new PHP script is begining with `require("path-toPHP file");`

Is it actually possible, how exactly to do it and is there another simpler way?

Thank you guys in helping me learn this language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're printing the ratio even when the form hasn't been filled in, and a ratio hasn't been calculated.

You need to do:

```
<p>Le ratio: <input type="text" name="ratio" <?php if (isset($ratio)) {echo 'value="'.$ratio.'"';} ?> /></p>
```

Also, you're not getting the values of the inputs correctly. It should be:

```
$A = $_POST['A'];
$B = $_POST['B'];
$C = $_POST['C'];
```

Comment: where I exactly put this line? If I try to call it just before p>Le ratio: <input type="text" name="ratio" value=<?php echo $ratio ?> /></p>, there seems to be an error...

Comment: You put it INSTEAD of the line you have.

Comment: Well, it works pretty nicely now. So, if I got it right, the problem resided in the fact that the value was output with "echo" even before it was actually calculated by hitting the button. But, how come variables are conserved after the script has been closed in the first place?

Comment: When you submit the form, the script starts fresh, and nothing is conserved. But since it's being run as a result of a form submission, the `$_POST` variables are filled in automatically with your form inputs.

Answer (score 0):

`$A = 'A';
    $B = 'B';
    $C = 'C';
    $ratio = (($B * $C) / $A);`

if you assign the value 'A' to $A, 'B' to $B and so on what is the point of the calculation?

to get the value from `<input type="text" name="A" />` into $A you have to call it like
`$A = $_POST['A']` and so on.

and as to your actual question about the $ratio not being set declare that variable outside of the `if(isset($_POST['ratio_calc']))` check because the variable would not be set if this check is not true and you will get the 'Undefined variable: ratio'

Comment: Thanks for the precision about values. I understand my mistake, and yeah my code didn't make any sens in the first place. But I don't get it about the $ratio thing. Could you explain a bit more just to be sure I get it?